# matplotlib svg requires plugin to view

Tags: django, matplotlib

I am trying to dymamically render an SVG image from matplotlib and insert it into the HTML document.

I am using Cairo.SVG as the matplotlib backend.

Now whenever I try to insert it into the

```
<img src="/url_to_graph" /> 
//or 
<object data="/url_to_graph" />
```

I either get nothing or the "Missing Plugins" error from Firefox.

FYI I am using Firefox. Also any other examples of SVG images I find on the web, work just fine - and require no plugin.

Does matplotlib render the SVG images in some special format I don't know about?

Comment: What's the mimetype in the "Content-Type" header of the server response? It should be set to "image/svg+xml".

Comment: Yap thats right... i didn't set the correct mimetype in django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/url_to_graph"></object>`?

`<img src="/url_to_graph"/>` *should* work.

Are you able to see the `svg` file with other applications?

My guess is that the file is correctly generated, but the webserver is sending them with an incorrect `mime-type`.